# AWS Scan on DynamoDB condition-expression option

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to scan item where some field called reason be a String with:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table --condition-expression "attribute_type(reason, :v_sub)" --expression-attribute-values file://expression-attribute-values.json
```

`expression-attribute-values.json` is:

```
{
    ":v_sub":{"S":"SS"}
}
```

I took the example from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html but I'm getting this error:

[image]

any hint?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `scan` operation does not accept `condition-expression` as parameter, avaible options are

```
--table-name <value>
          [--index-name <value>]
          [--attributes-to-get <value>]
          [--select <value>]
          [--scan-filter <value>]
          [--conditional-operator <value>]
          [--return-consumed-capacity <value>]
          [--total-segments <value>]
          [--segment <value>]
          [--projection-expression <value>]
          [--filter-expression <value>]
          [--expression-attribute-names <value>]
          [--expression-attribute-values <value>]
          [--consistent-read | --no-consistent-read]
          [--cli-input-json | --cli-input-yaml]
          [--starting-token <value>]
          [--page-size <value>]
          [--max-items <value>]
          [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
          [--cli-auto-prompt <value>]
```

However the `put-item` operation does accept a `condition-expression` and `--expression-attribute-values` parameters, see complete list below. Additionally, notice that a `condition-expression` is "A  condition  that  must  be  satisfied  in  order for a conditional PutItem operation to succeed"

```
  put-item
          --table-name <value>
          --item <value>
          [--expected <value>]
          [--return-values <value>]
          [--return-consumed-capacity <value>]
          [--return-item-collection-metrics <value>]
          [--conditional-operator <value>]
          [--condition-expression <value>]
          [--expression-attribute-names <value>]
          [--expression-attribute-values <value>]
          [--cli-input-json | --cli-input-yaml]
          [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
          [--cli-auto-prompt <value>]
```

By checking the docs, only `Condition Expressions` accept functions like `attribute_type`. See [Syntax for Conditions Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html) and [Condition Expressions Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html)

#### References

[Scan Operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html)

[Put-Item Operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/put-item.html)